# Error while using Unhex to get printable original values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, hex, hexdump

I am having a database with 1 table containing a Column "User_Data" in hex format. I want to extract these values Unhexed i.e printable values.

So I use the command:

```
Select UNHEX(User_Data) From DatabaseName.TableName
```

In result most values appear in error format like some special characters (pasted below) and not printable original values. Error result:

> ��W"��FW&�WB66�V�Bv�F�D��%$�D$�B�UB��ĔԕDTB�f��rW6W&��R�tEE$dT�v���W��&R��#b��2#��b�V6R

One example Values in Hex Column:

> 596f757220496e7465726e6574206163636f756e7420776974682044484c2042524f414442414e44204e4554205b505d204c494d4954454420686176696e6720757365726e616d652020414a57414454524156454c2077696c6c20657870697265206f6e20323031362d31302d30332032303a30303a313620506c656173652

Error Result Achieved via above UnHex command :

> ��W"��FW&�WB66�V�Bv�F�D��%$�D$�B�UB��ĔԕDTB�f��rW6W&��R�tEE$dT�v���W��&R��#b��2#��b�V6R

Actual Result should have been something like:

> Your Internet account with DHL BROADBAND NET [P] LIMITED having
>   username  AJWDTRAVEL will expire on 2016-10-03 20:00:16

Comment: Why are you storing strings in hex format? Just curious...

Comment: got it in hex format...just to add ... i am suing mysql gui on windows desktop.

Comment: Do you have line breaks inside your stored hex values? If so, please try UNHEX(REPLACE(User_Data, "\n", ""))

Also the character set may be a problem, enclose the unhex with CAST(UNHEX(...) AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8)

Where utf8 is the original character set used when stored the value.

Comment: is it possible for u to give exact full command ?

Comment: SELECT Cast(unhex(user_data) AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8) FROM DATABASENAME.TABLENAME - Still getting same issue ?